# Error on using glide - You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity

Tags: android, android-glide

When the activity is resumed, this error occurs. Tried using Glide.with(getActivity()).pauseRequests() or Glide.get(getActivity()).clearMemory() in the method onDestroy() or onDestroyView(), nothing is really working. Still getting this error. Also, tried cancelling all volley requests on destroy, still no luck.

> 07-02 13:07:24.788 1406-1406/? E/InputEventReceiver: Exception
>   dispatching input event.
>       07-02 13:07:24.800 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback 07-02 13:07:24.817
>   1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity 07-02 13:07:24.817
>   1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.b.a.e.o.b(Unknown Source)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   com.b.a.e.o.a(Unknown Source) 07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/?
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at com.b.a.e.o.a(Unknown Source) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   com.b.a.f.b(Unknown Source) 07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/?
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   io.mi.ra.kee.ui.adapter.ListViewAdapter$CellFeedViewHolder.a(Unknown
>   Source) 07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   io.mi.ra.kee.ui.adapter.ListViewAdapter.onBindViewHolder(Unknown
>   Source) 07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(Unknown
>   Source) 07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(Unknown
>   Source) 07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(Unknown
>   Source) 07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(Unknown
>   Source) 07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(Unknown
>   Source) 07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(Unknown
>   Source) 07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(Unknown Source)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollBy(Unknown Source)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.scrollVerticallyBy(Unknown
>   Source) 07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.scrollByInternal(Unknown
>   Source) 07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onTouchEvent(Unknown Source)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8388) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2424)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2158) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2430)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2739) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   io.mi.ra.kee.ui.activity.BaseActivity.dispatchTouchEvent(Unknown
>   Source) 07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.support.v7.view.n.dispatchTouchEvent(Unknown Source) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.support.v7.view.n.dispatchTouchEvent(Unknown Source) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8578) 07-02
>   13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4021)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3887)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3449)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3502)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3468)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:     at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3578)
>   07-02 13:07:24.817 1406-1406/? E/MessageQueue-JNI:    at
>   android.view.ViewRootImp

Comment: I have same problem , knock me if you find it .

Comment: @MehdiJahedManesh check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39096193/3960700)

Comment: @Alankrita Sood Try Glide.clear(imageView);

Answer (score 0):

This is answered in another question, but I worked around this issue by getting and using the ApplicationContext

```
                    Glide.with(context.getApplicationContext())
                            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
                            .load(storageReference)
                            .signature(new StringSignature(uri.toString()))
                            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                            .placeholder(placeHolder)
                            .into(imageView);
```